# Plot points on a graph based on time and price

Tags: pine-script

I am have never written a pine script saying I am a newbie is an understatement. I cant seem to find this online.

I am trying to plot 2 points on a EURUSD chart. I want to plot it to go back and review and grade my entry and exit.

First point is
time = '2023-03-01 15:46:02.000'
price = 1.06736

Second Point
time = '2023-03-01 17:41:15.000'
price = 1.06731

Then lastly draw line from point to point.

Comment: If you just want to draw fixed lines on the chart, you can use TraingView built-in drawing tools. It makes more sense, especially since you don't really know how to code at all (and from your question, not eager to learn just to make a simple task)

Comment: Thank you mr_starter if you have a link I would be glad to learn. I have not found a sample to plot a single point googling.  Also this is only 1 transaction I have over 100 transactions. Manual draw is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [line.new](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_line%7Bdot%7Dnew) (xloc.bar_time)
Something like that:

```
//@version=5
indicator("test", overlay = true)

i_timeFrom = timestamp("2023-03-01 03:46:02.000")
i_price    = 1.06736


if barstate.islast
    hl_q =  line.new(i_timeFrom, i_price, timenow, i_price, xloc.bar_time, extend.none, color.blue, line.style_solid, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you Gu5tavo71. The script does not fail it creates a line. I would like to create a dot at each location listed in question and then draw a segment from dot to dot. Thanks again.